# Where are these system header files?

Tags: objective-c, header-files

The files are float.h and limits.h. Are they somewhere in Xcode? When directions like these are given: `/Developer/SDKs/<insert SDK here>/usr/include` do I type them in somewhere or follow the directions one-by-one like a map?

Comment: Are you actually trying to locate them in the file system or just use them in code?  If the latter, `#import <float.h>` and Xcode should figure it out.

Comment: Yes, the first one I'm trying to find it and look in the contents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this:

- Write `CHAR_MIN` inside a file that you opened using X-Code.
- Right-click on `CHAR_MIN` and select `Jump to Definition`
- Right-click on an empty space inside `limits.h` and select `Show in Finder`

You can do this to find the location of any file of this kind.

In my system `limits.h` is inside the X-Code folder.